# Find out Last 30 Days, 60 Days and 90 Days in java

Tags: java, date

How to get last 30 / 60 / 90 days records from given date in java?

I have some records with receivedDate. I want to fetch the records for last 30 or 60 or 90 days from received Date. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use [java.util.Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Date today = new Date();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(today);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30);
Date today30 = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -60);
Date today60 = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -90);
Date today90 = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 24):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate                       // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.now(                           // Capture today's date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )   // Specify the desired/expected zone.
)                               // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.minus(                         // Subtract a span-of-time.
    Period.ofDays( 30 )         // Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline in terms of years-months-days.
)                               // Returns another `LocalDate` object.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The bundled java.util.Date & .Calendar group of classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later, and back-ported to Java 6 & 7.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### Date math

You can define a span-of-time in terms of years-months-days with the `Period` class.

```
Period days_30 = Period.ofDays( 30 ) ;
Period days_60 = Period.ofDays( 60 ) ;
Period days_90 = Period.ofDays( 90 ) ;
```

You can add and subtract a `Period` to/from a `LocalDate`, resulting in another `LocalDate` object. Call the [`LocalDate::plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plus(java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount)) or [`LocalDate::minus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#minus(java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount)) methods.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate ago_30 = today.minus( days_30 ) ;
LocalDate ago_60 = today.minus( days_60 ) ;
LocalDate ago_90 = today.minus( days_90 ) ;
```

You more directly call `LocalDate.minusDays`, but I suspect the named `Period` objects will make your code more readable and self-documenting.

```
LocalDate ago = today.minusDays( 30 ) ;
```

### JDBC

Sounds like you are querying a database. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can exchange *java.time* objects with your database. For a database column of a data type akin to the SQL-standard standard `DATE` (a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone), use `LocalDate` class in Java.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ago_30 ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## *Joda-Time*

**UPDATE:** The Joda-Time library is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator, Stephen Colebourne, went on to lead the JSR 310 and *java.time* implementation based on lessons learned with Joda-Time. I leave this section intact as history, but advise using *java.time* instead.

Here is some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library’s [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate thirty = now.minusDays( 30 );
LocalDate sixty = now.minusDays( 60 );
LocalDate ninety = now.minusDays( 90 );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "thirty: " + thirty );
System.out.println( "sixty: " + sixty );
System.out.println( "ninety: " + ninety );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-03-26
thirty: 2014-02-24
sixty: 2014-01-25
ninety: 2013-12-26
```

### Time Zone

The beginning and ending of a day depends on your time zone. A new day dawns in Paris earlier than in Montréal.

By default, the LocalDate class uses your JVM's default time zone to determine the current date. Alternatively, you may pass a DateTimeZone object.

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
```

Comment: Nice post. Very informative :)

Answer (score 2):

If you put 1 in xdaysago it means 1 day ago 30 means 30 days ago, you can look your zone id in ZoneId class.

```
 public static String getDate(int xdaysago){
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of( "Asia/Karachi" )).minus( Period.ofDays( xdaysago ));
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return localDate.format(formatter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure where you are fetching your data from but to compute the date that is say 30 days from now you can use the Calendar class's add function like so:

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30); //assuming c is of type java.util.Calendar

Now to figure out if a particular date is between today and 30 days ago you can use the before() and after() functions to figure out if the date was before today but after the 30th day before today.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I recommend you use Joda as your date&time library. Not only it has a superior API, but it understands (ie, has classes for) concepts like periods, duration and things like that.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using the Calendar, I needed to pick up the date minus N days from the current date. The best way was:

```
public Date getDateVariation(Integer variation, Date currentDate) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(currentDate);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, - (variation));
    return c.getTime();
}
```

**Variation** is o N day that i want 10/30/60/120 days.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Date daysAgo(int days) {
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);
    return gc.getTime();
}
```

Comment: FYI, as the adoption of JSR 310, the `GregorianCalendar` class is now supplanted by the `ZonedDateTime` class. But these both include a time-of-day as well as a date. For date-only work, better to use `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

code to get future date

```
    public String futureDateByFourMonths() {
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(currentDate);

    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); 
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

    Date currentDatePlusOne = c.getTime();

    return dateFormat.format(currentDatePlusOne);

}
```

Just change month and minus the number of months

```
public String pastDateByFourMonths() {

    Date currentDate = new Date();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(currentDate);

    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -4);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

    Date currentDatePlusOne = c.getTime();

    return dateFormat.format(currentDatePlusOne);

}
```

I found this solution somewhere and modified it for my need

Comment: These terrible date-time classes (`Calendar`, `Date`) were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.