# Convert Date in Millisecond to Today, Yesterday, Last 7 Days, Last 30 Days in Java

Tags: java, time

I have some documents and its created time is in milliseconds.
I need to separate them as Today, Yesterday, Last 7 Days, Last 30 Days, More than 30 Days.

I used the following code:`convertSimpleDayFormat(1347022979786);`

```
public static String convertSimpleDayFormat(Long val) {


            long displayTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - val;
            displayTime = displayTime/86400000;
            String displayTimeVal = "";
            if(displayTime <1)
            {
                    displayTimeVal = "today";  
            }
            else if(displayTime<2)
            {
                    displayTimeVal = "yesterday";
            } 
            else if(displayTime<7)
            {
                    displayTimeVal = "last7days";
            } 
            else if(displayTime<30)
            {
                    displayTimeVal = "last30days";
            }
            else
            {
                    displayTimeVal = "morethan30days";
            }
            return displayTimeVal;
    }
```

I am subtracting the current time and passing the milliseconds and converting to one day.

But the issue I'm facing is, I couldn't calculate the exact time for the date in milliseconds.

I want to calculate for Today as: From Midnight 00:00 to Midnight 24:00. (Exactly for 24 hours.)

Similarly I want to exactly convert the Milliseconds into Today, Yesterday, Last 7 days, Last 30 Days and More than 30 Days.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979469/find-out-last-30-days-60-days-and-90-days-in-java?rq=1 might help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
private static Calendar clearTimes(Calendar c) {
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    return c;
}

public static String convertSimpleDayFormat(long val) {
    Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
    today=clearTimes(today);

    Calendar yesterday=Calendar.getInstance();
    yesterday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-1);
    yesterday=clearTimes(yesterday);

    Calendar last7days=Calendar.getInstance();
    last7days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-7);
    last7days=clearTimes(last7days);

    Calendar last30days=Calendar.getInstance();
    last30days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-30);
    last30days=clearTimes(last30days);


    if(val >today.getTimeInMillis())
    {
            return "today";  
    }
    else if(val>yesterday.getTimeInMillis())
    {
        return "yesterday";
    } 
    else if(val>last7days.getTimeInMillis())
    {
        return "last7days";
    } 
    else if(val>last30days.getTimeInMillis())
    {
        return "last30days";
    }
    else
    {
        return "morethan30days";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi user1651840 
Thanks a lot for your answer. But I faced one issue, today.getTimeInMillis() returns the millisecond value of the current hour. So when i upload a document by 3.15 PM it returns "today" till 4.00 PM, after that it returns "yesterday". I want to return for the whole day so need to check millisecond from Today Midnight 12.

Comment: @jeevi I will check this but maybe it needs a bit

Comment: @jeevi why should it switch at 4:00 pm? Is there a time zone difference between your java environment and the file system?

Comment: --> I am not setting any Time Zone. Also its not switching exactly by 4pm. It check for the current hour only, when i upload one document now, till 5 pm it shows today and after 5pm it shows yesterday.

Comment: @ user1651840 Also i tried setting time zone as Asia/Calcutta in Calendar.getInstance(), but also same issue i am facing.

Comment: @Jeevi let run Calendar.getInstance().getTimezone() on both machines

Comment: @ user1651840 sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Kolkata",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null], i am getting this time zone only... but

Comment: @ user1651840 
I uploaded a document by 5.10PM now.. still its showing as Today. But will check after 6PM, whether it will move to Yesterday, to check for time zone issue or the issue is with today.getTimeInMillis() which returns the current hour millisecond.

Comment: @ user1651840
Hi its 6.05 PM now, the document is listing under Yesterday. I think its not an issue with TimeZone, but today.getTimeInMillis()  returns the current hours starting millisecond. So it returns today for the current hour, and after the hour passes, it returns yesterday.

Comment: @Jeevi I edited my example now it should work 'set' instead of 'clear'

Comment: @ user1651840 Thanks a lot its working as expected. Will test and let you know if any issues. Thanks once again. Have a great day

Comment: Thanks so much. You have no idea the amount of time this has saved me

Answer (score 0):

It's a small hack, not severely tested. Use at own risk. I've made it extensible so you can add new durations.

```
public static String prettyTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        c.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        c.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        c.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        long today = c.getTimeInMillis();
        final long oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
        final long[] durations = new long[] { today - oneDay, today,
                today + 7 * oneDay, today + 30 * oneDay };
        final String[] labels = "Yesterday,Today,Last 7 days,Last 30 Days,More than 30 Days"
                .split(",");
        int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(durations, timeStamp);
        return labels[pos < 0 ? ~pos : pos];
    }
```

By the way, you should really just use a Library like [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)